# Open Visual Studio Browser In Specified Display

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, multiple-monitors

I am running a local environment with two displays (laptop, monitor). The monitor is set up as my primary display.

When I build and launch my website for debug from Visual Studio 2013 the web browser always opens up on my primary display (monitor), I then move and maximize on my laptop.

Is there anyway to set it up so when I build and launch the browser automatically opens and maximizes on my secondary display?

Comment: Are multiple displays set up as "Extend these displays" in display settings?

Comment: Yes. They are extended displays.

Comment: Then the position and size of the window is (automatically) restored to the same state when the window was closed.